# floc and fscale in fitting Beta distribution in Scipy — getting FitSolverError

Tags: python, beta-distribution, scipy

I have a dictionary with unique ID and a list of floats as key/value pairs, e.g.: '101':[0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.41, 0.34, 0.54].  Each list of floats has at least 9 values long and always ranges from 0 to 1, inclusive. Not all samples will have a 0 or a 1 in them, but some do, and some have multiple 0's and multiple 1's, etc.

I'm trying to fit a beta distribution over each of the arrays to get a new dictionary that's unique ID/beta parameters as the key/value pairs, e.g. '101' : (1.5, 1.8).

Right now I'm just doing this with a for-loop, iterating over each thing thing in the dictionary:

```
beta_dict = {}
for i in my_dictionary:
    beta_dict[item] = stats.beta.fit(my_dictionary[item], floc=-.00000001, fscale=1.0000001)
```

When I loop over my_dictionary, after a while I get this error:

> FitSolverError: Solver for the MLE equations failed to converge: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the   improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.

I realize it has to do with specific examples/it's something with my floc and fscale. I think maybe specifically the fscale — the problem goes away when I get rid of my fscale. And when I change my fscale (from 1.0001 to 1.0000001 or so on), my code breaks on different items in the dictionary (like some of the dictionary items work with certain values of fscale and others don't).

So I guess my question is — do I need the fscale/is it safe to get rid of it? What's the fscale doing in the first place? At first I thought it was just setting the bounds/the range for the distribution of values in my sample (like, upper bound at fscale + floc) but given my code is breaking that seems to not be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) `floc` and `fscale` do the following:

> - floc : hold location parameter fixed to specified value.
> - fscale : hold scale parameter fixed to specified value.

So you are fixing the location and scale parameter, respectively. But the way you fix them, it is not surprising that no beta distribution can be fitted to the data. Your fixation $(\mu, \sigma)=(0,1)$ suggests that your data are centered around 0 with an average dispersion of 1, and thus can become negative. Your observations, however, are in the interval $[0,1]$, and so the solver may be unable to converge based on the initial restriction.

One solution would be indeed to get rid of both arguments. However, if you want to have comparable location and scale parameters for some reason, you may choose a more plausible fixation, e.g. $(0.5, 0.25)$.